# Header files without .h in C++

Tags: c++, linux, header-files

I'm having trouble including standard header files like `iostream.h` and `fstream.h`. On my system, under `usr/include/c++/4.3`, none of the files have the ".h" extension (for example, it's just *iostream* not *iostream.h*).

That would be fine and dandy, but I'm trying to use another library, DCMTK, which does things like `#include<iostream.h>`. Unfortunately, there's no such thing as "iostream.h" on my system, only "iostream", meaning my compiler gives me errors like `error: iostream.h: No such file or directory`.

I guess I could create softlinks from `iostream.h` to `iostream`, but that seems like it might create, first of all, troubles down the road, and second of all, be really irritating. Is there another solution?

Just for completeness, the command I'm giving to compile the thing is

```
g++ -o gc_on_ctp -g -Wall -Idicom/include -Ldicom/lib gc_on_ctp.cpp -ldcmdata
```

As you can imagine, the header file is located under dicom/include, and the library is under dicom/lib, named libdcmdata.a.

Comment: `iostream.h` and `fstream.h` are **NOT** standard header files.

Comment: To expand on @dan04's comment, the headers with `.h` are from the pre-standardised version of the C++ library.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the thorough and very quick answers! 

Also, just to avoid defaming the name of DCMTK, they actually do use the standard header files, I just needed to include a configuration header which set up some macros, apparently. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look [here](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html). It explains why and when this `iostream.h / iostream` was born, why it exists and how you should solve these issues.

Mainly `iostream.h` is to be considered <strike>**DEPRECATED**</strike> **UNRELIABLE** and **IMPLEMENTATION SPECIFIC** and using the `iostream` in place of that one can cause errors..

Comment: `Mainly iostream.h is to be considered DEPRECATED ` Nopes, `<iostream.h>` cannot be considered _deprecated_ because it was never a part of the standard. See Annex D(ISO C++-98) for the list of deprecated features.

Answer (score 6):

Just create a new iostream.h file that has a single line in it: `#include <iostream>`.  It seems to be a big mistake by DCMTK because the standard is that there should be no .h in these file names.

Comment: That's the common solution - Qt uses it among others. It used to be more common because some compilers wouldn't handle files without a .h !

Comment: Not to be confused with the <cstring> <string.h> headers issue. That's slightly different.

Comment: @Chris good point.  What I suggest *only* works for file <-> file.h

Answer (score 3):

Those headers are deprecated/pre-standard. On gcc I believe they're located as `#include <backward/iostream.h>` etc now.

On the other hand if the library you're linking against requires an older incompatible version of the standard library you might have further problems ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would fix the (outdated) library.  You can use in-place regex search and replace to do that:

```
perl -e "s/iostream.h/iostream/g;" -pi $(find . -iname "*.cpp")
```

or

```
find . -iname "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/iostream.h/iostream/g'
```

**NOTE:** Be careful when doing this... it affects all files recursively from the path you start from.